# THREE.js WebGlRenderer domElement getBoundingClientRect returns 0s in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, onload

I have the following code:

```
...
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true, alpha: true });
    renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
...
    controls = new TrackballControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
```

When running the above code in an iframe, PAN events don't fire. Investigation reveals that:

```
    console.log('???', renderer.domElement.getBoundingClientRect())
```

returns `DOMRect {x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0, top: 0, …}`

This results in all mouse move events being mapped to infinity, because there is no 'height' or 'width' until a resize event is called.

In general, it seems that dynamically adding a canvas to the DOM could result in weird timing errors when passing that element to plugins like TrackballControls.

What is the right way to ensure that we only use the canvas once it has actually loaded?

(cross posting from threejs forums: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/three-js-webglrenderer-domelement-getboundingclientrect-returns-0s-in-iframe/42948)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue when the iframe was cross-domain.

My solution was to simply set the screen size directly on the trackingball object.

My case was using [3d-force-graph](https://github.com/vasturiano/3d-force-graph) library, so the solution was like this:

```js
function onWindowResize() {
  Graph.controls().screen.width = window.innerWidth
  Graph.controls().screen.height = window.innerHeight
}
```

(the graph.controls() returns the trackingball object in this case, since this was the controlType set for the scene)

hope this helps.